# Why was this beginner's answer deleted ?

Tags: discussion, answers

[An answer by Ubuntu was deleted,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7819/why-does-venus-rotate-the-opposite-direction-as-other-planets) wrongly, in my opinion, as not being an answer.

He is offering an alternative answer which can be discussed as to how probable it is for Venus to be captured as is. He starts with a polite preamble but that is no reason to jump and delete the answer.

To those with < 10 k, https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3rLz.png

Comment: Most of his answer is basically a new question.  I think it' is ok to delete it.

Answer (score 6):

I think the way the answer was written has caused some confusion.

Indeed there is some answer in the text Ubuntu wrote, namely the innate spinning meteor theory. Most of the text however, especially the last sentence ("if you do not answer I will understand"), suggests that Ubuntu is rather asking a question. Or, really assuming the worst*, even hijack someone elses question for a question on his own theory.

So I can imagine that Qmechanic decided to delete it mainly based on the last part of the post, maybe without noticing the attempt at an answer in the first part.

*I am quite sure that he didn't mean to do that

Answer (score 5):

Ups, yes, I read it pretty quickly, and mostly noticed what seemed like a question at the end. I have no time to deal with it, so I'm just going to undelete the answer for now, removing the question and the greeting.

Answer (score 2):

Reading version 1 of the answer, my impression is that it was intended as a response to other answers (and comments). Sure, it includes something that *could* be construed as an answer to the question, but that answer is quite speculative, and not the kind of informed response we want to encourage. So I would also have deleted that answer.

Comment: I think David you are being overly strict to a new comer, who seems to be diffident and unsure of his/her welcome. I think the editing Qmecanic did is fine . I also think it is fine to contrast to other answers as it is fine to refer to them and add some extra info, no?

Comment: With combination of greeting, opinion and questions together, it is obviously that the user think it is a forum. Forwarding the user to ask a question and deleting redundancy part is enough. Even it is a new user, the answer is not spam, offensive and trolling, I see no urge to delete it immediately.

Comment: @annav It's fine to contrast to other answers, sure, as long as you are answering the question. This is not an issue of how to handle a newcomer vs. how to handle an experienced member. It's not an issue of welcoming people; that is not the purpose of the site. The purpose of the site is to let people ask questions and answer them. Anything that does not answer a question should not be posted as an answer to the question, simple as that. And I do not think the post was intended as an answer.